# Как спрятать в многострочном списке крайние разделители

Tags: javascript, html, css, layout

Есть список элементов, который может быть многострочным.
Пример:

```css
.container {
  width: 440px;
  text-align: center;
}

.item {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #ffd473;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 3px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.sep {
  margin: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span class="item">MenuItem1</span>
  <span class="sep"> ❤️ </span>
  <span class="item">Item2</span>
  <span class="sep"> ❤️ </span>
  <span class="item">SomeText</span>
  <span class="sep"> ❤️ </span>
  <span class="item">Hi all</span>
  <span class="sep"> ❤️ </span>
  <span class="item">MenuItem5</span>
  <span class="sep"> ❤️ </span>
  <span class="item">MenuItem6</span>
  <span class="sep"> ❤️ </span>
  <span class="item">MenuItem very long text</span>
  <span class="sep"> ❤️ </span>
  <span class="item">More text</span>
  <span class="sep"> ❤️ </span>
  <span class="item">More else text</span>
  <span class="sep"> ❤️ </span>
  <span class="item">item10</span>
</div>
```

Надо скрыть `sep` разделители  которые крайние.
У меня это
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Устраивают любые решения на css или js.
Размер и количество элементов меню заранне не известны. То есть решение должно работать при любых пунктах меню и любых размерах контейнера.

Comment: Нужно именно СПРЯТАТЬ ненужные, или можно показать только там где нужно?

Comment: @AndreyFedorov любым способом, спрятать, удалить, или вовсе не выводить.

Comment: Получите ширину блока, ширины каждого пункта меню и ширину сепараторов. Считайте где будут переносы.

Comment: @AndreyFedorov Это учебный вопрос. Я сам могу реализовать решение. А это 1. возможность поучиться и заработать балы для тех кто хочет. 2. реально интересный вопрос для StackOverflow. Поэтому пишем не идею алгоритма, а решение.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var spans = document.querySelectorAll(".container span");

spans.forEach((span, i) => {
  if (!span.classList.contains("sep")) return;
  var currentSpanL = span.getBoundingClientRect().left;
  if (
    !spans[i + 1] ||
    !spans[i - 1] ||
    currentSpanL > spans[i + 1].getBoundingClientRect().left ||
    currentSpanL < spans[i - 1].getBoundingClientRect().left
  ) {
   // span.parentNode.replaceChild(document.createElement('br'), span);
   span.style.visibility = 'hidden';
  }
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 440px;
  text-align: center;
}

.item {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #ffd473;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 3px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.sep {
  margin: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span class="item">MenuItem1</span>
  <span class="sep"> ❤️ </span>
  <span class="item">Item2</span>
  <span class="sep"> ❤️ </span>
  <span class="item">SomeText</span>
  <span class="sep"> ❤️ </span>
  <span class="item">Hi all</span>
  <span class="sep"> ❤️ </span>
  <span class="item">MenuItem5</span>
  <span class="sep"> ❤️ </span>
  <span class="item">MenuItem6</span>
  <span class="sep"> ❤️ </span>
  <span class="item">MenuItem very long text</span>
  <span class="sep"> ❤️ </span>
  <span class="item">More text</span>
  <span class="sep"> ❤️ </span>
  <span class="item">More else text</span>
  <span class="sep"> ❤️ </span>
  <span class="item">item10</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Что-то тут недодумано. После 6 отсутствует сердечко - вот как у меня выглядит - https://yadi.sk/i/0Z6sJYMfudz9Fg

Comment: Остаться ведь должно шесть с таким размером контейнера.После шестого  и перед пятым сердце убирается и на свободное место подтягивается длинный span.

Comment: тут попросту неоткуда взяться между ними сердечку.

Comment: Убираться должны только по краям. А все между остаться.

Comment: Замени display none на visibility hidden, тогда не будет смещаться

Comment: Проверять `left` - хорошая идея. Для того чтобы первый значимый элемент новой строки не перепрыгивал (на предыдущую), можно вместо скрытия разделителя заменять его на `<br>` (а через `visibility` неок, тогда элементы "поедут" в некоторых случаях).

Comment: @yar85 в каком случае поехать может?  Место которое элемент занимает ведь никак не меняется.

Comment: @hu-fo-of-ex, В том и дело, что занимаемое место не меняется, а элемент не виден. При центровке с невидимым элементом, видимые визуально сдвигаются в противоположную (от невидимого элемента) сторону.

Comment: @yar85 Спасибо. Классная идея заменить брейком. ++

Comment: Доработал немного решение, так как на практике пробуя применить у себя оказалось, что некоторые случаи данным алгоритмом не берутся. Зачёт отдаю этому решению, так как оно достаточно просто и лаконично.

Comment: в ff ни одного сердечка

Answer (score 2):

Тупенькое, но универсальное решение (кроме случаев когда разница высоты отдельных строчных элементов не может быть компенсирована порогом `threshold`):

```js
removeEdgeDelimiters('.container', '.sep'); 

function removeEdgeDelimiters(srcSelector, delimSelector, threshold = 0) {
  const srcEl = document.querySelector(srcSelector); 
  if (!srcEl) return null; 
  const copy = srcEl.cloneNode(); 
  copy.classList.add('hidden-copy'); 
  srcEl.insertAdjacentElement('afterend', copy); 
  copy.innerHTML = ''; 
  const lastDelimSel = delimSelector + ':nth-last-child(-n+3)'; 
  let prevH = 0; 
  for (const child of srcEl.children) {
    copy.appendChild(child.cloneNode(true)); 
    if (copy.scrollHeight - prevH > threshold) {
      const lastDelim = copy.querySelector(lastDelimSel); 
      lastDelim && lastDelim.replaceWith(document.createElement('br')); 
    } 
    prevH = copy.scrollHeight; 
  }
  srcEl.replaceWith(copy); 
  copy.classList.remove('hidden-copy'); 
  return copy; 
}
```

```css
.container { width: 440px; text-align: center; }

.item {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 3px; padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #ffd473; }

.sep { margin: 0 10px; }
.hidden-copy { position: absolute; left: -200vw; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span class="item">MenuItem1</span>
  <span class="sep"> ❤️ </span>
  <span class="item">Item2</span>
  <span class="sep"> ❤️ </span>
  <span class="item">SomeText</span>
  <span class="sep"> ❤️ </span>
  <span class="item">Hi all</span>
  <span class="sep"> ❤️ </span>
  <span class="item">MenuItem5</span>
  <span class="sep"> ❤️ </span>
  <span class="item">MenuItem6</span>
  <span class="sep"> ❤️ </span>
  <span class="item">MenuItem very long text</span>
  <span class="sep"> ❤️ </span>
  <span class="item">More text</span>
  <span class="sep"> ❤️ </span>
  <span class="item">More else text</span>
  <span class="sep"> ❤️ </span>
  <span class="item">item10</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Доработал вариант @hu-fo-of-ex добавив проверку по правому краю. Так как в случае левого края не попадали ситуации где разделитель изначально попадал не в конец строки а в начало.

```js
const spans = document.querySelectorAll(".container span");

spans.forEach((span, i) => {
  if (!span.classList.contains("sep"))
    return;

  if (!spans[i + 1] || !spans[i - 1])
    return;

  const currentSpanL = span.getBoundingClientRect().left;
  const currentSpanR = span.getBoundingClientRect().right;

  if (
    currentSpanL > spans[i + 1].getBoundingClientRect().left ||
    currentSpanR < spans[i - 1].getBoundingClientRect().right
  ) {
    span.parentNode.replaceChild(document.createElement('br'), span);
  }
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 370px;
  text-align: center;
}

.item {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #ffd473;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 3px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.sep {
  margin: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span class="item">MenuItem1</span>
  <span class="sep"> ❤️ </span>
  <span class="item">Item2</span>
  <span class="sep"> ❤️ </span>
  <span class="item">SomeText</span>
  <span class="sep"> ❤️ </span>
  <span class="item">Hi all</span>
  <span class="sep"> ❤️ </span>
  <span class="item">MenuItem5</span>
  <span class="sep"> ❤️ </span>
  <span class="item">MenuItem6</span>
  <span class="sep"> ❤️ </span>
  <span class="item">MenuItem very long text</span>
  <span class="sep"> ❤️ </span>
  <span class="item">More text</span>
  <span class="sep"> ❤️ </span>
  <span class="item">More else text</span>
  <span class="sep"> ❤️ </span>
  <span class="item">item10</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let items = document.querySelectorAll(".item");

for(let i = 0, max = items.length; i < max; i++) {
  if(i+1 < max && 
  items[i].getBoundingClientRect().left > items[i+1].getBoundingClientRect().left) {
    items[i].parentNode.replaceChild(document.createElement('br'), items[i].nextElementSibling);
  }
}
```

```css
.container {
  width: 440px;
  text-align: center;
}

.item {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #ffd473;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 3px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.sep {
  margin: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span class="item">MenuItem1</span>
  <span class="sep"> ❤️ </span>
  <span class="item">Item2</span>
  <span class="sep"> ❤️ </span>
  <span class="item">SomeText</span>
  <span class="sep"> ❤️ </span>
  <span class="item">Hi all</span>
  <span class="sep"> ❤️ </span>
  <span class="item">MenuItem5</span>
  <span class="sep"> ❤️ </span>
  <span class="item">MenuItem6</span>
  <span class="sep"> ❤️ </span>
  <span class="item">MenuItem very long text</span>
  <span class="sep"> ❤️ </span>
  <span class="item">More text</span>
  <span class="sep"> ❤️ </span>
  <span class="item">More else text</span>
  <span class="sep"> ❤️ </span>
  <span class="item">item10</span>
</div>
```